# compilemex in Statistical Pattern Recognition Toolbox in Matlab

Tags: matlab, svm, mex, statistics

I am new to [Statistical Pattern Recognition Toolbox](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/cmp/software/stprtool/) in matlab.
I am trying to use the oaasvm function in this toolbox. Before using this I need to run the compilemex.m. But when I run it I get the following error

```
>> compilemex
Compiling MEX files of STPRtool...
mex -O -IC:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\stprtool\kernels -outdir C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\stprtool\kernels C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\stprtool\kernels\kernel.c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\stprtool\kernels\kernel_fun.c 
Error using mex (line 206)
The destination directory "C:\Program" cannot be found.

Error in compilemex (line 113)
  eval(mexstr);
```

Can anyone tell how shall I proceed to run the oaasvm code?

Comment: I edited your question to add a link to what I think is the Toolbox you're referring to. It doesn't appear to be a product from The MathWorks.

Comment: The last update to that product was two years ago... You're likely to have more luck contacting them or debugging it yourself (though I suppose there's a small chance someone here has used this).

Comment: It seems that the space in `Program Files` is not recognized. Hence the code looks for `Program` which it can't find. Not sure if there is anything you can do without either installing Matlab somewhere else or modifying `compilemex.m` to handle a space in your path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Schorsch in the comments, you need to add quotes around path strings to handle spaces in them.

The fix is easy, edit the file [`compilemex.m`](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/cmp/software/stprtool/manual/root/list/compilemex.html), look for the following section (line 102), and make the below changes:

```
% -- Compile functions -----------------------------
for i=1:length(fun),
   mexstr = ['mex -O -I''' translate(fun(i).include,root) ...
             ''' -outdir ''' translate(fun(i).outdir, root) ''' '];

  for j=1:length(fun(i).source),    
    mexstr = [mexstr '''' translate(char(fun(i).source(j)),root) ''' '];
  end

  fprintf('%s\n',mexstr);

  eval(mexstr);
end
```

Basically I've added single quotes (escaped by singe quote) around path strings. The result is that the commands executed will be of the form:

```
mex -O -I'C:\Documents and Settings\Amro\Desktop\stprtool\kernels'
    -outdir 'C:\Documents and Settings\Amro\Desktop\stprtool\kernels'
    'C:\Documents and Settings\Amro\Desktop\stprtool\kernels\kernel.c'
    'C:\Documents and Settings\Amro\Desktop\stprtool\kernels\kernel_fun.c'
```

Note that you dont have to place this package inside the MATLAB installation. You can place the extracted folder anywhere on your system, as long as you add it to the MATLAB path `addpath`